# IndexError: list index out of range error while enter value like 1 2 3 in Python

Tags: python, list, index-error

I am generating a graph/drawing using pyhton.
When I am entering value from backward like `6 5 4 3` it's working fine but When I am giving input like `1 2 3` it's throwing list index out of range error.
I am new to python. Please help me to fix this.

**EDIT : ** it's only accepting when first value is greater than second value for example it's working with 7 6 but not with 6 7.

[image]

here is my python code:

```
HUMAN_HEIGHT = 3    
HUMAN_WIDTH = 3
HUMAN_LEG_OFFSET = 1


def print_2d_array(arr):
    """Print the 2D Array"""
    print(f"Height = {len(arr)}, Width = {len(arr[0])}")
    for row in arr:
        for item in row:
            print(f"{item}", end="")
        print()


def increasing_slope(index):
    """Returns if the slope is increasing which is the even number"""
    return index % 2 == 0


def get_indicator(index):
    """Returns the indicator for increasing or decreasing slope"""
    return "/" if increasing_slope(index) else "\\"


def add_human_at(new_arr, human_location, height):
    """Adds Human to the Array"""
    human_x = human_location[0]
    human_y = human_location[1]
    
    new_arr[height - human_y - 1][human_x - 1] = " "
    new_arr[height - human_y - 1][human_x] = "○"
    new_arr[height - human_y - 1][human_x + 1] = " "
    new_arr[height - human_y][human_x - 1] = "/"
    new_arr[height - human_y][human_x] = "|"
    new_arr[height - human_y][human_x + 1] = "\\"
    new_arr[height - human_y + 1][human_x - 1] = "<"
    new_arr[height - human_y + 1][human_x] = " "
    new_arr[height - human_y + 1][human_x + 1] = ">"


def create_line(y0, x0, y1, x1, index):
    """Generator that Returns the diagonal line from x,y to x1,y1"""
    
    yield y0, x0
    
    while y0 != y1 and x0 != x1:
        
        y0 = y0 + (-1 if increasing_slope(index) else 1)
        x0 += 1
        
        yield y0, x0


def get_2d_mountains_from_1d_sum(arr, height, width, human_location):
    
    new_arr = []
    for i in range(height + HUMAN_HEIGHT):
        mountain_row = []
        for j in range(width + HUMAN_LEG_OFFSET):
            mountain_row.append(" ")
        new_arr.append(mountain_row)

    
    ground = height + HUMAN_HEIGHT
    
    prev_x, prev_y = 0, 0
    for index, [x, y] in enumerate(arr):
        
        indicator = get_indicator(index)

       
        if prev_x >= human_location[0]:
            start_x, start_y = ground - prev_y - 1, prev_x + HUMAN_LEG_OFFSET
            end_x, end_y = ground - y - 1, x - 1 + HUMAN_LEG_OFFSET
        
        else:
            start_x, start_y = ground - prev_y - 1, prev_x
            end_x, end_y = ground - y - 1, x - 1

        
        for (point_y, point_x) in create_line(start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y, index):
            new_arr[point_y][point_x] = indicator

        
        prev_y = y
        prev_x = x

    
    add_human_at(new_arr, human_location, height)
    
    print_2d_array(new_arr)


def generate_mountains(nums):

    sum_nums = []
    sum_at_position = 0
    previous_sum = 0
    total_width = 0
    max_height = 0
    human_location = []
    for index, item in enumerate(nums):
        # + or - numbers to get prefix list
        if index % 2 == 0:
            sum_at_position += (item - 1)
        else:
            sum_at_position -= (item - 1)

        
        total_width += abs(sum_at_position - previous_sum) + 1

        
        if sum_at_position > max_height:
            max_height = sum_at_position
            human_location = [total_width, max_height]

        previous_sum = sum_at_position
        sum_nums.append([total_width, sum_at_position])

    get_2d_mountains_from_1d_sum(sum_nums, max_height + 1, total_width, human_location)


def print_mountains_human_from_input(nums):
    generate_mountains(nums)


print("Enter the inputs")
a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

print_mountains_human_from_input(a)
```

I added the screenshot of error..
thanks in advance.

Comment: probably sharethe part of the code that is affecting not the  complete code, that will be helpful to debug

Comment: Have you tried `print`ing or using a debugger to inspect the values of `new_arr`, `point_x`, and `point_y` on line 82?

Comment: It's only accepting when first value is greater than second value for example it's working with 7 6 but not with 6 7.

Comment: Do you only want to input ascending (1, 2, 3 ..) and descending (...3, 2, 1) numbers? What do you expect, if you input ascending order (1, 2 ,3 )?

Comment: Have you tired to sort your numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [sorting](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/sort) to your function to avoid a wrong input error but it will not fix the actual error:

```py
def print_mountains_human_from_input(nums):
    nums.sort(reverse=True)
    generate_mountains(nums)
```